# example Objective-C project calling Objective-C++ code

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

Anyone know of an example project of a Objective-C project calling Objective-C++ code.

I've read all the stackoverflow q's about getting one to call the other but no luck.
Would help if I had a code sample that worked.

The Obj-C++ I have is a lib .a and some c++ headers. Thats all.

Comment: What do you mean by *"no luck"*? What are the problems that you have?

Comment: @clearbrian you need to show the code and the errors you receive. It's very hard to tell what's going wrong form the information you provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's example project I made, it's actually easy to undestand, you can just rename your classes from .m to .mm or in project settings set "Compile sources as" to Objective-C++. I have had some trouble with C++ headers which didn't have C++ implementation as well - changing settings to compile everything as Objective-C++ helped.

Here's the code https://github.com/libec/StackOverflow/tree/master/03-Obj-C%2B%2B

Answer (score 0):

Here's a contrived example. Without more information about what you're trying to do, or the errors you're receiving, it will be impossible to guide you much further. Remember that any code that calls C++/Objective-C++ code or imports a header that includes C++-isms must be compiled as Objective-C++ (use the `.mm` extension and Xcode will automatically do the right thing).

```
/*Objcpp.h
**********/
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{}
- (void)myMethod;
@end

/*Objcpp.mm
***********/
#import "Objcpp.h"

@implementation MyClass

- (void)myMethod {
  //some c++ and/or objective-c calls
}
@end


/*myobjc.h
***********/

@interface MyObjCClass : NSObject
{}
- (void)someMethod;
@end

/*myobjc.mm
***********/
#import "myObjCClass.h"
#import "Objcpp.h"

@implementation MyObjCClass

- (void)someMethod {
  MyClass *o = [[MyClass alloc] init];
  [o myMethod];
}
@end
```